# Why GridBagLayout don't create third column?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I need to create a form with 3 columns and 5 rows

```
+---+-----------+
|   |           |
|   +-----+-----+
|   |     |     |
|   +-----+-----+
|   |     |     |
|   +-----+-----+
|   |     |     |
|   +-----+-----+
|   |     |     |
+---+-----+-----+
```

But GridBagLayout puts all the elements in the form whith 2 columns:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Lab7_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        buildFrame("Groups");

    }

    public static void buildFrame(String name){
        JFrame fr = new JFrame(name);

        //Создание переключателя окна
            JButton JBMore=new JButton("<html>><br/>><br/>></html>");
        //Создание переключателя окна

        //Создание последней - информационной панели
            JPanel jp2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            JLabel jl = new JLabel("Select the person");

                ArrayList<JLabel> arrLabel = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
                ArrayList<JTextField> arrText = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
                for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
                    arrLabel.add(new JLabel(""));
                    arrText.add(new JTextField(""));
                    //jp2_2.add(arrLabel.get(i));
                    //jp2_2.add(arrText.get(i));
                }
                arrLabel.get(0).setText("Age:");
                arrLabel.get(1).setText("Address:");
                arrLabel.get(2).setText("Telephone:");
                arrLabel.get(3).setText("Favorite color:");

            c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
            c.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
            c.weighty = 1.0;
            c.weightx = 0.1;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.ipadx = 0;
            jp2.add(JBMore,c);  

            c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 20, 10);
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            c.gridheight = 1;
            c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            c.weightx = 1;
            c.weighty = 0.01;
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 0;
            jp2.add(jl,c);

            c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.insets = new Insets(2,10,10,10);
            c.gridwidth = 1;
            c.gridheight = 1;
            for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
                c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
                c.gridx = 1;
                c.weightx = 0.05;
                c.gridy = 1+i;
                c.weighty = 0.05;
                c.ipadx = 0;
                jp2.add(arrLabel.get(i),c);

                c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
                c.gridx = 2;
                c.weightx = 0.05;
                c.ipadx = 10;
                //jp2.add(arrText.get(i),c);
            }


        //Создание последней - информационной панели

        fr.add(jp2);

        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.pack();
        fr.setMinimumSize(fr.getSize());        
    }

}
```

Try uncomment this line[87]:

```
//jp2.add (arrText.get (i), c);
```

and you will see that all the elements are shifted to the left

---

Commented line 87:

[image: Commented line[87]]

Uncommented line 87:

[image: Uncommented line[87]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE in the width of the left column means to only leave room on the right of it for one column. You might want to change the width of that button to `1`.

**Side Note:**

Shouldn't it be this:

`<html>&gt;<br/>&gt;<br/>&gt;</html>`